# How can I emit a warning (but not an error) when a default template instantiation is being used as opposed to a specialized?

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a semi-library (a piece of code that is used in my company by many engineers over a long time). I would like to put a compilation warning if a particular templated function isn't specialized by a dev. The desired behaviour is that it shouldn't break the build (the software will run just fine), but a missing implementation should be clearly visible during the build process.

I have settled on using the `deprecated` keyword, since it is the only context aware warning I could find that displays the template instance type so that the error can be easily located.

The following code is my desired behaviour and works correctly:

`bar()` is the templated function which I want

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename foo> [[deprecated("using default implementation")]] void warning() {};

template<typename foo> void bar();
template<typename foo> void bar() { warning<foo>(); std::cout << "default" << std::endl;};
template<> void bar<double>() { std::cout << "double" << std::endl;};

template<> void bar<int>() { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; };

int main(int, char**)
{
        bar<int>();
        bar<float>();
        bar<double>();
}
```

On gcc 12, the above code correctly emits the following warning:

```
minimal.cpp:5:49: warning: ‘void warning() [with foo = float]’ is deprecated: using default impementation [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    5 | template<typename foo> void bar() { warning<foo>(); std::cout << "default" << std::endl;};
```

The output of the program is:

```
int
default
double
```

However, if I move the definition of `bar<int>` to a different compilation unit, there is a warning issued for it, even though the runtime behaviour is correctly specialized.

**Edit**: adding verbatim code that produces problem

in unit.cpp

```
template<typename foo> void bar();
template<> void bar<int>() { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; };
```

in minimal.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename foo> [[deprecated("using default implementation")]] void warning() {};

template<typename foo> void bar();
template<typename foo> void bar() { warning<foo>(); std::cout << "default" << std::endl;};
template<> void bar<double>() { std::cout << "double" << std::endl;};

int main(int, char**)
{
        bar<int>();
        bar<float>();
        bar<double>();
}
```

Command line: `g++ minimal.cpp unit.cpp -o test`

Compilation result:

```
minimal.cpp:5:49: warning: ‘void warning() [with foo = int]’ is deprecated: using default implementation [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    5 | template<typename foo> void bar() { warning<foo>(); std::cout << "default" << std::endl;};
minimal.cpp:5:49: warning: ‘void warning() [with foo = float]’ is deprecated: using default implementation [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    5 | template<typename foo> void bar() { warning<foo>(); std::cout << "default" << std::endl;};
```

(warnings elided for brevity)

Runtime output:

```
$./test
int
default
double
```

I have an inkling as to why this happens: the unspecialized template is used until a specialized instance is found, and given that I can squirrel away the specialized instance outside of a compilation unit *without* declaring it, this must be done by the linker. Which would make sense as to why the compiler is unable to detect and prevent the spurious deprecation warning.

Furthermore, I can't put the generic template definition in a compilation unit without explicitly forward declaring every possible instance in my header (which defeats the purpose of templates anyways).

This leaves me with the following question: how can I warn a user of a library when they are reverting to a generic template instantiation at compile time?

---

**Final Edit**: from the looks of it, this is not achievable because the spec: see [here](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#2138) for a discussion on the language standard, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58729125/4514378) for a discussion on SO.

The missing definition warning works well when the code is in the same translation unit, but doesn't work well when spanning multiple translation units.

With regards to my specific problem, I believe the best way forward is to put template specializations inside hpp files (at the cost of lengthier compilation durations).

Thank you all for quick feedback.

Comment: Do you declare the specialization?

Comment: Did you try declaring the specialization, `template<> void bar<int>();`?

Comment: If not, you would have ill-formed program, NDR.

Comment: Better to show problematic code instead of (only) the correct one.

Comment: Problematic code is exactly this code with the function moved into a separate cpp file. I will make a clear example, but there's nothing different.

Comment: "if I move the definition of bar<int> to a different compilation unit" sounds like you are violating the One Definition Rule

Comment: No, I am not. This is standard template programming, I'm just looking for a warning that isn't standard. I've updated the listing above, it compiles in gcc, and you can see that `bar<int>` is only defined once. More importantly the linker correctly uses the specialized template instance.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: forward declaring the specialization does work. However, it makes the code not DRY and more importantly, it forces the dev to jump through a hoop to make the warning go away while also unnecessarily touching a header file. As it stands, I will have to rely on this if all else fails, but I would really like to simply be able to add the implementation into the compilation unit and not do anything else (think "adding function definition to foo.cpp and leaving foo.h untouched").

Comment: Without **declaring** the specialization (before the point of use), your code is ill-formed No diagnostic required.

Comment: @Jarod42 Note the comment from Jarod42. In particular, the emphasis should be on making the code well-formed first. Then and only then you should try to make the code "DRY". There's no point in having a DRY code/program that is ill-formed.

Comment: "This is standard template programming." No it isn't. Without the declaration of the specialization it is IFNDR, as Jarod says. The mere coincidence that the linker resolves the symbol to what you want is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, thanks, digging around I found [this](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#2138) dating back to 2015 but still left as ill-formed by design. The example in there is almost literally exactly the same as my code above, btw.

Comment: @user12002570 an attempt to make code more ergonomic should be the highest priority of library and professional code writers. Pushing this boundary is something we should continue to do every day all day without hiding behind the fear that it might be IFNDR today.

Be that as it may, it appears this issue was raised nearly a decade ago and was (hopefully) purposefully designed to be this way.

Comment: No. The "highest priority of library and professional code writers" is to make the code well-formed, and compliant with the C++ standard.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik spoken like a true compiler. Yes, ill formed code is assumed to be non-code.

Comment: A final note on the legality of this whole thing https://stackoverflow.com/a/58729125/4514378

Comment: Going into my 10th year on Stackoverflow, this is the first time I am accused of being a compiler. There's a first time for everything.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik hmm. I tried to bring humour into the conversation which was running dry. When talking about pure dry compiler spec stuff that falls under the realm of "language lawyering", do you not take that as an underhanded compliment?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm proud of being called a compiler.

Comment: *"the software will run just fine"* -- Then why warn? It seems like you've got conflicting aims -- one where you don't force the programmer to specialize the template (so at most a warning) and one where you do force the programmer to specialize the template (so at least a warning). Your code would be more ergonomic if you picked one aim and dropped the other -- either error out or don't complain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)